# search for a word in argument in C

Tags: c, arguments

I have the following code:

```
  host = argv[1];

  if ((argv[1]) = "http://"); {{
    host = host + 7;
  }
```

the host is a url which is entered by argument it can be either http://google.com or www.google.com

so I want to check if the arguments contains "http://" and remove it by removing the first 7 characters is there such a function in c?

Comment: Comparing char pointers won't work. Use `strcmp()` (or `strncmp()` if you only want to compare the first 7 characters.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *host = argv[1];
  if (strncmp(argv[1], "http://", strlen(argv[1])) == 0) {
      host = host + 7;
  }
  printf("%s\n", host);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply but I need to use the host variable as this is part of a long program so all I want to do is to check if there is "http://" in the argument and cut it my way host = host + 7;  The http:// is always start of the argument so these are the first 7 characters for sure.

Comment: I see! Yeah, your way accomplishes it as well, and is arguably cleaner than mine(I like explicit pointer arithmetic). strstr() is what you're looking for!

Comment: There, edited the answer to reflect your code, the way you want to use it.

Comment: Actually, strncmp is better in this case, as @squeamish-ossifrage said, since you only want to compare a limited number of characters from the strings.

Comment: I have done it here is the working code:   if ((strncmp(argv[1], "http://", 7)) == 0) {
     host = host + 7;
  }  Thank you for your help!